# Use onEdit(e) to change the date contents of a cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I paste date values to my spreadsheet with the format `MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:ss` and use `onEdit(e)` to have them changed to `MM/DD/YYYY`.

I'm able to achieve that, but the problem is that when I select a cell containing a date, the format in the cell shows up as `MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss`.

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var source = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  source.getRange("A2:A").setNumberFormat("MM/DD/YYYY");
}
```

This is what I see when I select the cell:

[image]

Is it possible to remove `hh:mm:ss` from it altogether?

I would be grateful for any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recommendation:**

Use `toLocaleDateString()` to return date as a string. This will remove the timestamp.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var source = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var dates = source.getRange("A2:A").getValues(); 

  dates.forEach((x,i) => {
    var el = new Date(x).toLocaleDateString();

      if(el != "Invalid Date"){
      source.getRange("A"+(i+2)).setValue(el);
      }
    });
    
}
```

**References:**

- [toLocaleDateString](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocaledatestring.asp)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, @Serenity! I was actually able to resolve the issue using `Utilities.formatDate()`, but I think this is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this method:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  let dt = new Date();
  sh.getRange("A2:A" + sh.getLastRow()).setValue(new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate())).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

Which just enters the time at midnight. (ie time is 0000);  Now the data line only displays the date

Comment: Thank you for this answer, @Cooper! This works if all the dates in the column are the same, but it won't work in my spreadsheet because all the dates on it are different. I modified your code to achieve what I'd like, and it uses `toLocaleDateString()` like the other answer.